# Limiting bandwidth of the of Amazon aws s3 uploads

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm currently having daily backups of my files on uploaded to S3 bucket using `aws s3 mv` command, i.e.:

```
aws s3 mv $webroot/backups/db/ s3://my-backups/$date/db
```

Everything works, except that recently my host (MediaTemple) started automatically disabling my server, because, apparently, those uploads started hitting some traffic bytes per second limits that are in place on all their servers.

Is there some way to limit the bandwidth of the `aws s3 mv` using parameters or aws configuration options?

I understand there are some 3rd party Linux utilities that can do that. I.e. throttle or trickle. However, I'd like to avoid additional software, if there's a built-in way to do that with Amazon's own tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mv` command has no such option to throttle bandwidth. You can see the full options list here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html

There are some configuration values you can customize to control S3 transfers commands (cp, sync, mv, and rm).

For example, setting the value of `max_concurrent_requests` to a value lower than 10 (which is the default), will make it less resource intensive. Have a look at the link below and try to adjust the values and see if it helps.

[See details here: AWS CLI S3 Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try reducing `max_concurrent_requests` and see if that helps. I'm not uploading a lot of files, just a few really large ones. So I'm not sure if the S3's multipart chunked uploads are considered "concurrent requests" or not.

Comment: Looks like reducing `max_concurrent_requests` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it worked!

Comment: Per that article there is now a "max_bandwidth" option available as well.